# Codeigniter can't catch exception from expired JWT token

Tags: php, codeigniter, jwt, codeigniter-4

so I want to check JWT token every time I refresh the page, I use it as a filter, it goes well if the token is not exists or get discarded, it would go to login directly. But when the token is expired, Codeigniter would always turn to page exception with JWT token expired, and would not take the exception and direct it to login page with flash data.

**jwt_helper.php**

```
function validateJWT($token)
{
    $session = \Config\Services::session();
    $model = new UserModel();
    $key = getenv('JWT_SECRET_KEY');
    try {
        $decoded_token = JWT::decode($token, new Key($key, 'HS256'));
        return $decoded_token;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        setcookie('COOKIE-SESSION', null);
        $session->setFlashdata('message', '<div class="p-4 mb-4 text-sm text-red-800 rounded-lg bg-red-300 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-red-400" role="alert">
                <span class="font-medium">Token Invalid</span>, Please login again
              </div>');
        // echo $e->getMessage();
        return redirect()->to('/auth');
    }
```

It always display the exception telling that the token is expired instead of redirect it to the login

I've tried to wrap it in another try catch when I call the function, but it still not catch the error, and instead, it give me another `RedirectResponse`

[errorexception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7V0Pp.png)

`Undefined property: CodeIgniter\HTTP\RedirectResponse::$email`

**DashboardController.php**

```
public function show()
    {
        $session = \Config\Services::session();
        $token = $_COOKIE['COOKIE-SESSION'];
        $model = new UserModel();
        helper('jwt');
        try {
            $decoded_token = validateJWT($token);
            $result = $model->show($decoded_token->email);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $session->setFlashdata('message', '<div class="p-4 mb-4 text-sm text-red-800 rounded-lg bg-red-300 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-red-400" role="alert">
            <span class="font-medium">Session Expired</span>, Please login again
            </div>');
            return redirect()->to('/auth');
        }
        if (!$result) {
            $data['title'] = 'Login';
            $session->setFlashdata('message', 'Session expired, Please login again');
            return view('login', $data);
        } else {
            $data = [
                'title' => 'Dashboard',
                'email' => $result['email'],
                'name' => $result['name'],
                'image' => $result['image'],
                'date_created' => $result['date_created']
            ];
            $session->set('title', $data['title']);
            return view('dashboard', $data);
        }
    }
```

**UserModel.php**

```
public function show($email)
    {
        $session = \Config\Services::session();
        $model = new UserModel();
        $builder = $this->table('users');
        $data = $builder->where('email', $email)->first();
        if (!$data) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $data2 = [
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'image' => $data['image'],
                'date_created' => $data['date_created']
            ];
            return $data2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this the lib you are using? https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt

Comment: yes, that is the lib I use

Comment: Wrap your code inside these exceptions: https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt#exception-handling

Comment: still same, the exception in the `validateJWT()` wont bite, its getting error in when I try to use the `decoded_token` for parameter for email payload. 

theoretically the exception should catch before I pass the payload right ?

Comment: Can you check what `$decodedToken` returns?

Comment: it returns view in the form of string, anyway I already found the problem, 

turn out the `validateJWT()` return a view in the form of string, so it inserted in the `decoded_token` anyway 

I fix it by not using`validateJWT()` and decode each token using JWT::decode and then wrap it in ` ExpiredException `